# dart double dot notation awaits futures?

Tags: dart, syntax, refactoring

Quick question, I create this `File` object, write content to disk using it, and  then return it from inside an async function like so:

```
...
File file = await makeFileObject(filename);
return await file.writeAsString(content); 
// fyi writeAsString returns Future<File>
```

but I then I refactored it using the `..` notation, and it says it doesn't need the `await` after `return`

That's weird. Does `..` await the write?

Am I returning the `File` object before the write occurs or the `File` object returned by `writeAsString`?

```
...
return (await makeFileObject(filename))
    ..writeAsString(content);
```

Is the refactor functionally equivalent to the original?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the refactor is not equivalent to the original.  `x..y` evaluates to `x` and discards whatever `y` evaluates to.  In your case, that means that you discard the `Future` returned by `writeAsString`, and it therefore would not be `await`ed.  If you want your function to return only after `writeAsString` completes, you cannot use it with `..`.

If you want to avoid having the `file` variable, you would need to do:

```dart
return await (await makeFileObject(filename)).writeAsString(content);
```

However, I think that the original is more readable, and I would stick with that.